# Project files issue

Tags: ios, xcode, svn

I have added images in my application(Current working copy of SVN) by Right Click on the folder -> Add files to image folter, after that all the files in my application shows with '?' symbol . 
[image]

Please guide me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: are you copying the files to your project or just reference ?

Comment: Adding new files. Right Click - > Add Files to folder ->Select Image - > Click Ok.

Comment: You need to add them to the repository by right clicking on them and select add. Then it'll display a letter A instead of ? mark. Then click on thm select commit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select All** the files with **question mark**. You need to select them, after that right click & under **source control**, Select **"Add"**.

Then only when you'll commit the files, Those files will be added to SVN.

Comment: I have changed all the '?' state to 'A' state by "Select All the files with question mark. You need to select them, after that right click & under source control, Select "Add". " If i commit, is this give any effect in SVN source copy ?

Comment: It'll submit all those files marked with "A" to SVN. Those files will now be added to svn once commit.

Comment: Actually i have added 2 new images in to the project. All the existing files only marked as '?' then only i did the above process. So all the files are already there. That's why i ask.

Answer (score 2):

"?" indicates that these are not added in Repository yet. If you want to add these to repository follow below steps-

1. Select all these fils.
2. Right click on it
3. Source Control -> Add

This will mark your files to add in Repository. Then you need to commit changes.